# TypeError: notes.push is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am running a simple piece of code as shown below.

Basically I want to read the data that is already in 'notes-data.json' and then append it.

```
node notes.js
```

```
console.log('Starting notes.js');

const fs =  require('fs');

var addNote = (title, body) => {
    var notesString = fs.readFileSync('playground/notes-data.json');
    var notes;
    notes = JSON.parse(notesString);
    var note = {
        title,
        body
    };
    notes.push(note);
    fs.writeFileSync('playground/notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(note));

};

addNote("Hi", "There");

module.exports = {
    addNote: addNote
};
```

Expected: When I run this program it has to add "Hi There".

Actual: Getting the below error.

```
(base) prakashp:newproject2 prakashp$ node notes.js 
Starting notes.js
/Users/prakashp/training/nodejs/practise/newproject2/notes.js:13
    notes.push(note);
          ^

TypeError: notes.push is not a function
    at addNote (/Users/prakashp/training/nodejs/practise/newproject2/notes.js:13:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/prakashp/training/nodejs/practise/newproject2/notes.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:499:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:436:3)
```

If I comment the below line, I am not getting any errors.

```
notes = JSON.parse(notesString);
```

Please help.

Comment: You `push` on an array. Unless the result of `JSON.parse` is an array, you cannot do that (e.g. `JSON.parse("[1, 2, 3]")`).

Comment: Thanks for that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json file should have an array. Here is the working code you are trying to run on `repl` site. After the JSON Parse, your variable needs to be an array so you can use `push` method onto it.

Also I found one more mistake, instead of saving `note` to your json file, you should be saving `notes`. As you will overwrite on object again to the file & will cause the app to crash again.
Use this below line.

`fs.writeFileSync('playground/notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));`

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/repls/AridDecisivePixels)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should let us see what ./playground/notes-data.json looks like.

If the json file isn't an array, then you would most likely not be able to push anything onto it.

Comment: ```{"title":"secret2","body":"Some body here 2"}```

Comment: So your json is an object, and is not an array.

Objects do not have a 'push' prototype, so it makes sense that you cannot push a new note.

an example of a valid array json would look like this:


`[
  { 
    "title": "title1",
    "body": "body1"
  }
]`

Comment: Thank you so much.